# CodeIgniter - Active Record Caching for an insert query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am currently attempting to create a fairly basic web app that has the potential to hold sensitive(ish) data for users and their organizations.

I had intended on storing all user entered record data in one db and all app data in another db.This data will be stored in a shared db with an user_id and org_id against all records in all tables to facilitate separation.

To minimize risk of code error and data compromise I have researched the ability to automatically append standard 'where' statements to my active record queries using [Active Record Caching](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#caching)

```
$this->db->start_cache();
$this->db->where('user_id',$_SESSION['user_id']);
$this->db->where('org_id',$_SESSION['org_id']);
$this->db->stop_cache();
```

This is brilliant and will save a lot of headaches. However, According to the documentation
 http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#caching I should also be able to use this for updates (set method):

> Note: The following statements can be cached: select, from, join, where, like, group_by, having, order_by, set.

Looking at the active_record class "DB_active_rec.php" there is code present to provide caching in several methods (select, where etc).

```
if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
{
...do caching stuff
```

From what I can tell this seems to be missing from the set method.

I'm not sure what answer I'm after but hopefully it will be that I'm just doing it wrong!

Comment: I'm having an issue understanding, what are you trying to accomplish? Active Record caching gives you the ability to re-use parts of your queries. For example, your `->where()` would be put over to your next SQL statement.

Comment: Steven, my requirement was to ensure that data is ALWAYS filtered by org_id and user_id from these tables. This can be done by active record caching, my confusion lay with inserting data wherein I also wanted to automate the insertion of these values. I think their docs were misleading to suggest that caching was available for the set method. My question now I suppose would be how i might go about automating the insertion of these two fields on all table insert queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cache update statements. It would not make much sense.
In your update you use the `$this->db->where()`method, which essentially is a select. That part can be cached, and by doing that you save yourself a select statement.

Comment: Ok, I definitely see what you mean, a cached where statement would be incorrect to involve in a insert query. In which case their docs are slightly wrong but thats neither here nor there. Is there a way to auto'magically populate this information or must it to be done for each model / query?

Comment: You can't use it in an insert, because there no where clausule. You CAN use it with update. If you do ->('where x = 1') in a SELECT, you can use it to update something later on. So what I ment is that you cant  cache the actual update, but you can reuse the WHERE part of the update.

Comment: Aha! so set refers to an update! Don't know why that didn't compute originally. My desire to automate the insertion of this data is probably not practical. Thanks Robert.